# Alternative to using a subquery - can't create view in Mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery, view

I have created a view that pulls a range of rows based on a calculation; using this script (per this question: [How to select Range of rows based on field values - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34547808/how-to-select-range-of-rows-based-on-field-values-mysql)  :

```
select t.*
from curdataEvents t cross join
     (select max(revs) as maxrev from curdataEvents) x
where t.revs >= x.maxrev - 100000;
```

This pulls the range of rows I need. In order to get the desired report - I have to create multiple views each creating the next layer of the report. The problem is MySQL won't create a view using a subquery. Any ideas on how to re-write the script above that would yield the same results but allow me to create a view? I have tried multiple variations using a UNION clause, etc. What's tripping me up is this is a join to itself. The examples I've found so far using multiple tables. Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery, just not in the FROM clause. Just move it to the WHERE clause;

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS 
SELECT t.*
FROM curdataEvents t 
WHERE t.revs >= (SELECT MAX(revs) - 100000 AS maxrev FROM curdataEvents)
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25046/1).

Comment: EXCELLENT!! I guess I had been working on it for so long I was starting to overcomplicate it. Thanks! Works like a charm!