# How to over come "Result consisted more than one row" in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this to select the course that the student is studying:

```
SELECT course_student.course from course_student inner join
(select student.student_id from student inner join reg_user 
on student.reg_user = reg_user.reg_user_id
WHERE reg_user_id=5) as tmp 
on tmp.student_id = course_student.student into @vcourse;
```

However, as reg_user_id=5 will returns 2 rows because this student takes 2 courses, the following query which return all the students in the same course as user 5, returns error "Result consisted more than one row".

```
select family_name, middle_name, given_name FROM reg_user
inner join (select reg_user from lecturer inner join course_lecturer
on lecturer = lecturer_id
where course = @vcourse) as temp on temp.reg_user = reg_user_id;
```

I know this problem is due to using SELECT...INTO query but I don't know how to solve it. If anyone know how put more than one results into the WHERE condition, I'm really appreciated. Thank you
Ps: Here is the database structure so that you can follow my queries
[image]

I want to get all the result from the first query and using those result in the second one. 
The first one will select all the course_id for student_id=5.
The second one will select all the name of the register users who are students and in the same course as the student with id=5.

Comment: Use LIMIT 1 (if any one value works for you!) If you need to consider all the values, then your query needs to be approached differently

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do and provide sample data and desired results.  I don't see the relationship between the two queries.

Comment: I tried to rewrite things the way I would do it myself, guessing which table each column belonged to, and merged the two queries into one. See if this gets you the result set you want or if it is incorrect:

        SELECT ru.family_name, ru.middle_name, ru.given_name 
        FROM reg_user ru
        JOIN lecturer l on ru.reg_user_id = l.reg_user
        JOIN course_lecturer cl on l.lecturer_id = cl.lecturer
        JOIN course_student cs on cl.course = cs.course
        JOIN reg_user ru2 on s.reg_user = ru2.reg_user_id
        WHERE ru2.reg_user_id=5

Comment: I have edited my post so that it is easier for you to follow. I want to get all the values in the first query and using them in the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem, I see several solutions:

- either review the query so that it returns only one line. For example by adding a LIMIT clause 1
- either store the result in a temporary table instead of a variable
- or work with CURSOR to be able to process each line returned by the request in the host program

Comment: Can you explains to me two last solutions because I want to get all the result, not just 1. Thank you

Comment: Solution 2: use "INSERT INTO temp_table SELECT <your first query>" then use temp_table in the second select like this : ...WHERE course in (SELECT course FROM temp_table)...
Solution 3 : the goal is to write a stored procedure by declaring a CURSOR with the first select and loop the resultset using a LOOP block where you FETCH each record from the CURSOR : you get the course name you can then use into the second select. But this solution need to write a stored proc which is dependent of the SQL database engine, so not portable.

Comment: Thank you. It works like a charm.

Comment: How can I use your second solution with views?

Comment: I think you can use view like this: CREATE VIEW temp_view as SELECT <your first query>. This creates a _stored_ view in your MySQL database (as opposite to _derived_ view) that you can use in subsequent queries. Hope this helps !

Comment: I mean, I want to create a <temp_table> and then the view is defined as: create view <abc> as select...where course in (select course from <temp_table>) but MySQL does not allow me to do that.

Comment: In MySQL, you cannot use subqueries in FROM clause of a view. Have a look at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34597807/alternative-to-using-a-subquery-cant-create-view-in-mysql). May be it can give you hint for a solution.